# C++ How to refresh to get newest .dll files in a folder?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm using some .dll files of the 3rd party in my software and store in the following directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\path\to\dll\xxx.dll

After upgrading and deploying some new .dll files successfully, I reload these .dll files by invoking LoadLibrary function:

```
LibWaApiDll = LoadLibrary(tsDllPath.c_str());
fvsetup = (WAAPI_SETUP)GetProcAddress(LibWaApiDll, WAAPI_SETUP_NAME);
```

then I try to get the version of one (not all) .dll file by my code.
However, the returned result is the version of the old .dll file without the new version which has just deployed.

When unloading .dll files, I invoked "teardown" function of 3rd party and FreeLibrary function as follows:

```
iRet = fvteardown();
if (LibWaApiDll != NULL) FreeLibrary(LibWaApiDll);
if (LibWaUtilsDll != NULL) FreeLibrary(LibWaUtilsDll);
if (LibWaHeapDll != NULL) FreeLibrary(LibWaHeapDll);
```

What is the reason why my app still load the old .dll file after deploying?

How to refresh the .dll file to make sure that I can use the newest one?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If `LoadLibrary()` is not being provided a full path  (e.g. being supplied a relative path, or a library name without the containing directory specified) then it searches in a set of directories, and opens the first dll with a matching name it finds.    If that's not your situation, you need to provide more information (namely a [mcve] that can be used to recreate a similar symptom, and a description of what folder (or folders) contain the dlls being opened).

Comment: You could use Process Explorer to know which DLLs are actually loaded and from where. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer